# Confusion over InputIterator semantics/concept requirements

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

The C++ `InputIterator` is one of the most limited type of Iterator Concept.  It is only guaranteed to support dereference, equality comparison, pre-increment and post-increment (and post-increment and dereference)

Because `InputIterator` objects often iterate over an arbitrary stream, you can't even be sure that iterating twice over the same input will yield the same values.

I'm confused, though, if the dereference operator, `operator *`, is guaranteed to return the same value every time you dereference it, provided that you never increment the iterator.

For example, assuming `std::begin(some_input_stream)` returns an object that meets the `InputIterator` concept requirements, and `it` is not equal to or past the end position:

```
auto it = std::begin(some_input_stream);
auto value1 = *it;
auto value2 = *it;
assert(value1 == value2);
```

Is `value1` guaranteed to be the same value as `value2`?  (Providing, of course, that whatever type `*it` yields implements sane equality comparison semantics)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is `value1` guaranteed to be the same value as `value2`?

Yes. In fact, you could also copy the iterator, and that copy is guaranteed to give the same result *until* you increment one of the iterators:

```
auto it2 = it;
auto value3 = *it2;
assert(value3 == value1);

++it2;
auto value4 = *it; // ERROR: might not be dereferencable any more
```

This is specified by the requirements for `*a` in C++11 Table 107 (Input Iterator requirements):

> If `a == b` and `(a,b)` is in the domain of `==` then `*a` is equivalent to `*b`.

and, after `++r`:

> Any copies of the previous value of `r` are no longer required either to be dereferenceable or to be in the domain of `==`.

Comment: In fact the last quote is pretty important, since the answer to *"if the dereference operator, operator *, is guaranteed to return the same value every time you dereference it, provided that you never increment the iterator."* only holds as long as you don't increment any possible copies of the iterator either.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it must work. The requirements placed on `InputIterator` effectively force the implementation to cache the the last-read value, which is then returned by `operator*`.